# How do I see which disk I am booting from?

Tags: boot, hard-drive

I have two disks with the exact same partitioning and size. When I start the computer it obviously only boots from one of the disks. How can I tell which one?
(I have used `sudo fdisk -l`, but that will list the disks but since they have the same partitioning and size, I do not get a clue on which one is getting booted from)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Executing `mount` without any parameters will give you a list of all mounted drives. The one mounted to `/boot`, or `/` if there is no `/boot`, is your boot device.